# Javascript Function that validates exponent equations

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is a hw assignment.  The answer/output I want is correct. I just don't understand why.  I want the output to be true if the power function matches the number I am checking against.  I do get the answer true for these examples, but I don't understand how this recursive function is working.

In the else of this function, I am saying base * the function itself. what does that even represent?  How can `base * power(base, exponent - 1);` even compute? Shouldn't it just run in a circle and then finally end?

```
console.log(power(2,4) === 16);
console.log(power(2,3) === 8);
console.log(power(2,2) === 4);

var power = function(base, exponent) {
    if(exponent === 0) {
        return 1; 
    }
    else {
        return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: return base * power(base, exponent - 1); should be changed to return base * power(base, Math.abs(exponent) - 1); (bug: power(2, -4);)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function power returns an integer, so when the function returns `base * <some_integer>` is a perfectly valid expression. The best way to trace these things is with a pen and paper:

call stack of power(2,4):

```
power(2, 4) = 2 * power(2, 3)
power(2, 3) = 2 * power(2, 2)
power(2, 2) = 2 * power(2, 1)
power(2, 1) = 2 * power(2, 0)
power(2, 0) = 1 <--base case
```

now all you have to do is substitute the values up the call stack

```
power(2, 4) = 2 * 8 = 16
power(2, 3) = 2 * 4 = 8
power(2, 2) = 2 * 2 = 4
power(2, 1) = 2 * 1 = 2
```

Comment: `return base * power(base, exponent - 1);` should be changed to `return base * power(base, Math.abs(exponent) - 1);` (bug: `power(2, -4);`)

Comment: @Alon That would be `Math.abs()` in JS.

Comment: @Alon I am confused, why did you post that in response to my answer? Shouldn't you post that on the main question?

Comment: Sorry @HunterMcMillen, This was the answer I voted for and I thought its worth mentioning. I post my comment on the main question as this issue is not associated to your answer.

Comment: I understand that the exponent parameter decreases by one each time through and that eventually the return value becomes 1.  

But how does "power(2, 4) = 2 * 8"?    

Isn't "return base * power(base, exponent - 1);" saying to multiple the base value (2 in this example) by whatever is returned by the power function with the parameters of 2 and 1 less than the previous exponent.  

I'm not sure where a number is calculated at all.  It seems like the function just lowers the exponent until it can exit without calculating anything.

Comment: @MonuMan5 The right operand of the expression is a method call, so it doesn't have a value immediately. It's value is the return of that method call. In the case of recursive methods, the calls get chained like I showed above until you reach a base case. After you reach the base case the values just get substituted up the call stack like I showed above.

Comment: thank you sooo much Hunter, i really appreciate the help.  I had a "Oh!!!  I get it!" moment after that last comment of yours.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to write the function using Javascript's syntactic sugar declaration style:

```
console.log(power(2,4) === 16);
console.log(power(2,3) === 8);
console.log(power(2,2) === 4);

function power(base, exponent) {
    if(exponent === 0) {
        return 1; 
    }
    else {
        return base * power(base, exponent - 1);
    }
};
```

If you want, you can also add the line

```
console.log("power("+base+", "+exponent+")");
```

at the head of the function, to watch the recursive call sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The exponent is being reduced with each recursive call until it is equal to `0` where it will return a constant `1`, and the function stops being recursive.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9DZWM/).

Also, if this wasn't homework, there is [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) :)

Answer (score 0):

For the example of power(2,4), we have

- 4 != 0 so else executes and it performs 2*power(2,3).
- 3 != 0 so else executes and it performs 2*power(2,2).
- 2 != 0 so else executes and it performs 2*power(2,1).
- 1 != 0 so else executes and it performs 2*power(2,0).
- Finally 0 == 0 so it returns 1 and it doesnt perform another recursive call.

So it goes back through the calls and comes to 2*power(2,0) which we know power(2,0) == 1. That returns as 2. 
    Then it goes back to 2*power(2,1) and we know power(2,1) == 2 since [2*power(2,0)]. This returns as 4.

---

See the pattern? And so on until we get back to 2*power(2,3) ==16 since we have power(2,3) == 8 since [power(2,2) * power(2,1) * power(2,0) * 1]. Hope this helped!